# $_item->getProduct()->getShortDescription() & getShortDescription() Not displaying in frontend email

Tags: product, sales-order, frontend, order-email

`$_item->getProduct()->getShortDescription()` returns blank when used in a frontend email.

If I use send email in Sales > Orders in admin it displays. I tried setting the Attribute to global. Any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento **does not save product short description** on **sales_flat_order_item** table,So you can not get data **short_description**to order email to sales order item related any object

You need  to save **short_description** to this table  using create new field to `sales_flat_order_item` table.

Or you need load `product Model Object(Mage::getModel('catalog/product'))` by `$_item->getProductId()`.

```
$product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());

// check product is exit in system 
if($product->getId()):
$product->getShortDescription()
endif;
```

Comment: I accept the answer. Do I have to do more.Thank You your Answer worked great.